# "Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection" when I use general hostname in MobaXterm

Tags: linux, ssh, hostname, mobaxterm, frontend

To connect to a remote Red Hat machine in a cluster, the SSH command needed is as follows,

```
ssh -X -i id_rsa -t username@JumpHost ssh -X username@FrontEndHost
```

since there is a jump host named JumpHost. For balanced workload, JumpHost assigns front-end host automatically. So, FrontEndHost is only a general name for the actual front-end host. This SSH command works well in terminal.

Now I wanna setup this SSH connection in MobaXterm. If I fill up the Remote host in Basic SSH settings with the general name FrontEndHost, I got an error

> Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection

when I connect. But I can connect correctly if I fill up the Remote host field with the actual hostname of a front-end host, say for example, FrontEndHost1.

I wish to use the general front-end name in Remote host, and I know it is possible. That the connection works with actual front-end hostname means other settings of MobaXterm have no pronounced problem; the only difference is the Remote host field being the general front-end hostname. I don't know where the problem is and how to fix it. Can you please help me with this issue? Thank you.